# Is it possible to know how much a process has consumed its STDIN when terminated?

Tags: linux, shell

Suppose that I have a program (only the executable, no source code), an input file for it which consists of several test cases, and another file that consists of the expected output for each test case.

At the end of the first run of the program, how can I know how much, i.e. till which position, it has consumed the input file? Is there any commands or utilities on Linux for that purpose?

Comment: You can probably use `strace` to see the `read()` systemcalls it makes and their offsets...

Comment: Simplest would be for the program to count data as you read.